# iPhone CorePlot - Strange error

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-plot

I downloaded the CorePlotSDK, installed it using the readme instructions: copied the coreplotsdk directory to ~/Library/SDKs/ - imported  in the PCH file - added $HOME/Library/SDKs/CorePlotSDK/${PLATFORM_NAME}.sdk to the additional SDKs and -ObjC -all_load -lCorePlot to the other linker flags setting.

Now, if I try to build the project, I get this error:

Internal error occurred while creating dependency graph: *** -[NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: SDKRootPath)

What's that?!? I've never seen it and google can't help.

Comment: Ditto. This happens with Xcode4, though; can you comment if you are seeing this problem with Xcode4 or Xcode3?

Comment: Hi Brad, I'm sorry I never saw this comment! I really can't remember what the problem was.
Anyway thank you, I watched your course on iTunes U! It was really helpful!

Comment: That was actually my comment, not Brad's. :)